# Scala 2.2.4 with Secure Social and Facebook login

Tags: scala, facebook-graph-api, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I've taken over a project which uses SecureSocial 2.1.4 and is running Scala 2.2.4

I looked at updating, and decided that as the app is in such disrepair and hasn't been updated in so long, I'd just do a rebuild in a different language (I've done almost no Scala).

Today, it looks like an update to the Facebook API has broken logins.

I'm trying to figure out the quickest path to getting logins back, but can't figure out what is the best version to update to, and how to get that to work nicely with the simplest version of scala.

In the Build.scala, it shows

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4",
"com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2" exclude("org.scala-stm", "scala-stm_2.10.0"),
```

When I try to update to 2.10, I get

```
[warn]  :: ws.securesocial#securesocial_2.10;2.10: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.10;2.2: not found
```

In play.plugins, it has

```
1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin    
9994:securesocial.core.DefaultAuthenticatorStore
9995:securesocial.core.DefaultIdGenerator
```

I did manage to get a build using

```
"ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "M3.0-M1"
```

When I run the app using securesocial 2.1.4 and try to login, the only error I see to get is
Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown

```
    [error] application - Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown
securesocial.core.AuthenticationException: null
    at securesocial.core.OAuth2Provider.doAuth(OAuth2Provider.scala:117) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at securesocial.core.IdentityProvider.authenticate(IdentityProvider.scala:75) ~[securesocial_2.10-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at securesocial.controllers.ProviderController$$anonfun$handleAuth$1.apply(ProviderController.scala:92) [securesocial_2.10-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at securesocial.controllers.ProviderController$$anonfun$handleAuth$1.apply(ProviderController.scala:88) [securesocial_2.10-2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220) [play_2.10-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
```

The ultimate solution would be if I could update my model to work with the new facebook changes to the API

-------------- UPDATE ---------------

Doing more research, it appears the issue may be that Facebook is returning valid JSON tokens rather than url encoded as they had been before

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

Now, just trying to figure out how to update that in scala or secure_social

Comment: As I see from the source code, your version of securesocila parse JSON token: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/2.1.4-for-play24/module-code/app/securesocial/core/OAuth2Provider.scala#L72-L83

Anyway, can you try the newest securesocial version ?

Comment: Thanks @AndriyKuba, can you clarify which 'newest version? I've just tried ` "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4-for-play24"`, but that is not found. I'm already on 2.1.4 - I've tried M3.0 as well, but couldn't get it to build. I'm on Play 2.2.4, which I think is quite different from later builds.

Comment: Also, I've just checked the code you've pointed to against a patch I've been working on, and the Oauth2provider buildInfo is the same in both branches

Comment: ok, then other way, did you try to enable debug ? There are strings in the code that coudl give you a little more inforamtion: `Logger.debug("[securesocial] got json back [" + json + "]")`, `Logger.debug("[securesocial] user = " + user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using 2.1.4 I suggest you create a new Facebook provider that does not override the buildInfo method in OAuth2Provider and register that instead of the built in one.

That should get you going quite fast.